# помогите в unity 3D воспроизвести звук по кнопке

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Есть старый скрипт под *unity 4* (сишарп но в тэги явы запихаю )

```js
using Unity.Engine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sounds : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClip din;

    void OnMouseDown() {
        if(this.name == "din") {
            audio.PlayOneShot(din);
        }
    }
}
```

Но в 5 версии просит заменить на `GetComponent<AudioSource>`: пишет не поддерживает старый вариант. Я изменил как он просит, но он по-прежнему подчеркивает красным и выдает ошибку.

Вот вариант как я попробовал адаптировать его под 5 версию:

```js
using Unity.Engine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sounds : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip din;
    void OnMouseDown() {
        if(this.name == "din") {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(din);
        }
    }
}
```

В чем ошибка? Может есть еще вариант скрипта, по которому будет воспроизводится звук при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: `подчеркивает красный и выдает ошибку.` - Что за ошибку пишет?..... у вас , кстати, `name` в классе нету.........и что значит `сишарп но в тэги явы запихаю`?

Comment: А мои вопросы в игноре..хм...ну ок...

Comment: нет извиняюсь я не игнорировал просто места не хватило на комент. символов много а тут всего порядка 700. сишарп в тэги явы это значит я код хотел заключить в тэги но он на языке C# а там тока 4 на выбор (jawa HTML и еще два не помню) вот я и заключил код на сишарп в тэг JAWA/

Comment: ошибку error cs 0117 `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for PlayOneShot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using Unity.Engine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sounds : MonoBehaviour 
{
   public AudioClip din;
   AudioSource audio;

   void Start()
   {
      audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
   }

   void Update()
   {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) //здесь задаете  любую кнопку
            audio.PlayOneShot(din);
   }
}
```

Должно работать.

Comment: спасибо все ok )

Comment: @aivengos Очень рад что помог вам)) Закройте пожалуйста вопрос))

Comment: одна проблема ток осталась и я закрою. все ошибки исчезли но PlayOneShot по прежнему подсвечивается в MonoDevelop красным. пишет ошибку error cs 0117 `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for PlayOneShot

Comment: в самом Unity ругается на скрипт так: Assets/Editor/scripts/Sounds.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Unity' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: AudioSource audio; добавьте После public AudioClip din;

Comment: @aivengos забыл написать)))

Comment: Странно в самом редакторе MonoDevelop ошибок больше нет. Но стоит сохранится и перейти в Unity и попытаться воспользоваться скриптом как не дают.Пишут дескать исправьте скрипт.  В самой консоли Unity (Console) делает уведомление :

Assets/Editor/scripts/Sounds.cs(7,21): warning CS0108: `Sounds.audio' hides inherited member `UnityEngine.Component.audio'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

Возможно это глюк самой Unity? ведь редактор не ругается и явных ошибок ведь нет. Но повторюсь что в скрипте не чего красным уже не подсвечивает. Спасибо.

Comment: Не нравится ему имя переменной (видимо) могу ошибится

Comment: @aivengos Добавили AudioSource audio;?

Comment: Добавил. И обнаружил свою ошибку. расположение скрипта. сменил папку все заработало. тему можно закрывать. спасибо за помощь. P\S как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Пометьте ответ как верный, должно сработать(я и сам тут недавно))..)

Comment: хм. может перейдем в личку что бы не засорять тут тему. не могу найти где пометить верный. может мне пока неположено

Comment: @aivengos Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.